# US Visa with ACRO Record Deletion

Tags: visas, usa, uk

Consider someone (UK Citizen) who had been arrested but had *No Further Action* taken by the CPS (i.e. arrested and **not** charged with an offence) then **successfully** applied for the record to be deleted via ACRO.

They will therefore have no record of the arrest on:

- The Police National Computer;
- [A police certificate](https://www.acro.police.uk/Police-Certificates), or;
- [A subject access request](https://www.acro.police.uk/Subject-access-(1)).

US Visa applications (DS-160 form) ask: "Have you ever been arrested or convicted for any offence or crime, *even though subject of a pardon, amnesty or other similar action*.

From what I understand, pardons or amnesties are given to people who are **convicted** (i.e. proven or admitted guilt) of an offence but later "un-punished" (for want of a better word!):

- [Pardon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pardon): "...a government decision to allow a person to be relieved of some or all of the legal consequences resulting from a criminal conviction".
- [Amnesty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amnesty) "an official pardon for people who have been convicted of political offences".

**Would such a person be required to answer "yes" to this question?  I.e. is the ACRO deletion process covered by "other similar actions"?**

The only place a record could still exist would be on the local police force's system (they are not always deleted alongside the PNC record) - plus any paper records that the person arrested kept.

I've seen posts saying the US has no access to UK records and would therefore have to request via Interpol - which of course is not routine practise for every single Visa application.

Could any future partnership between the two countries change their current level of visibility to include such a deleted record?

**Should the person choose to answer "no", would the US be able to see any records of this arrest?**

Comment: Your second question basically acknowledges that you were arrested, then asks whether you should lie about it.

Answer (score 4):

> Would such a person be required to answer "yes"

Well,

> Have you ever been arrested

Yes, you have been arrested, there are no ways around it. The fact that a prosecutor didn't take action on your case didn't rewrite the facts.

From the [US embassy in the UK](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/ineligibilities-and-waivers-2/arrest-caution-conviction/) :

> If you have ever been arrested, cautioned and/or convicted of an offense anywhere in the world, you are required to declare it when applying for a visa.

> They will therefore have no record of the arrest on:

The Personal data [VCU01 form](https://uk.usembassy.gov/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/2016/08/VCU01_London.pdf), that you are required to fill if you say *Yes* to that question in the DS160 states

> **Section Two:** Fill in this section if the police certificate from the Association of
> Chief Police Officers (ACPO) states "No Trace" or "No Live Trace" or does not list, in
> full, your arrests/cautions/convictions.

This is obviously your case here, and then you will need to fill

> **Section Six:** Fill in this section if you have ever answered "YES" to any of eligibility
> questions on the visa application form DS-160 that have not been fully explained in
> Sections Two to Five. Please review the information you have provided for accuracy

with all the details

---

You must answer **Yes** to the DS160 question and explain your case in the VCU01 form